Unreal, Mask out player model that overlaps a weapon for sprite sheet export
I am able to create an animation sequence and export 8 frames for walking as a sprite sheet.
I want to export the player model without a weapon (which I have done)
I want to export the weapons separately to keep the file size small.
When the weapon is facing the camera I need the players hand to be cut out through it otherwise it would look strange floating next to the hand.
Using Unreal Engine 5.4 and Movie Render Queue for export
I tried setting the player model to black, but that hasn't helped, making the player model transparent didn't work, looking for any help.
I tried creating 2 instances of the player object, one holding the weapon with the player model invisible,
The other had the weapon invisible and the texture turned to black.
I have also tried to remove the black player model with photoshop, but leaves too many artifacts.
Player model and Weapon
Need the black to be transparent
